# Copy and paste from a data validation list

Tags: vba, excel

I have written the below code. I have 3 worksheets: `Dashboard`, `Workings` and `Data`. I have a data validation list on worksheet(`Dashboard`) which has a long list of companies.
I want to be able to select a company from the list, press a button and then match from a company list in the worksheet data which has plenty of other columns for corresponding data for that company. I want to be able to take certain data from the company chosen and paste it into the next available row in worksheet (`Workings`). The list in the worksheet (data) has multiple entries for the same company, hence why I have added a loop in here.

This code does no give an error but does not give any result.

Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong

Many thanks.

```
Sub pull_data()

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled

CompanyListLocation = Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(2, 4).Value
'Company = Worksheets("Data").Cells(CompanyListLocation, 1).Value

For x = 2 To 1000000

If Worksheets("Data").Cells(x, 5).Value = CompanyListLocation Then

Worksheets("Data").Cells(x, 5).Copy
Worksheets("Workings").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Worksheets("Data").Cells(x, 14).Copy
Worksheets("Workings").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Worksheets("Data").Cells(x, 15).Copy
Worksheets("Workings").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues


End If

Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: `Worksheets("Data").Cells` just cells I presume would be "Dashboard"

Comment: You are right, thanks, missed that, but still no luck with the code

Comment: same with `rows.count`  you can just say `worksheets("Workings").range("a1").value=worksheets("Data").range("a1").value`, no need to paste special values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to copy all the data from Data Sheet in column A of Workings Sheet?

You may try something like below. Tweak it if required.

```
Sub CopyData()
Dim wsCriteria As Worksheet, wsData As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
Dim CompanyListLocation
Dim lr As Long, dlr As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set wsCriteria = Sheets("Dashboard")
Set wsData = Sheets("Data")
Set wsDest = Sheets("Workings")
CompanyListLocation = wsCriteria.Range("D2").Value
lr = wsData.UsedRange.Rows.Count
dlr = wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
wsData.AutoFilterMode = False
With wsData.Rows(1)
    .AutoFilter field:=5, Criteria1:=CompanyListLocation
    If wsData.Range("E1:E" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count > 1 Then
        wsData.Range("E2:E" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy wsDest.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2)
        wsData.Range("N2:N" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy wsDest.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2)
        wsData.Range("O2:O" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy wsDest.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2)
    End If
    .AutoFilter
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

If you want to copy values only, change the copy paste code to this...

```
If wsData.Range("E1:E" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count > 1 Then
    wsData.Range("E2:E" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    wsDest.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    wsData.Range("N2:N" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    wsDest.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    wsData.Range("O2:O" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    wsDest.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If
```